# Makefile header file dependencies

Tags: makefile

I am doing a programming assignment and was asked to create a makefile.  It is supposed to have targets: run, main.o, project.o, and clean. My program contains files main.cpp and project.h and i don't understand what to use as dependencies for project.o or why project.o is necessary as a target.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a matching source file for `project.o`, there is no reason to include a target for it in your makefile.